# Why not use native lazy loading (image attribute loading="lazy") always?

Tags: image, load, native, lazy-evaluation

I try to get my head around the relatively new img attribute "loading".

I understand that if an img has the attribute loading="lazy" then it will tell the browsers that support the attribute, that it can be loaded when getting near the viewport.

So why not always set loading="lazy"? Those images that appear instantly on the screen would get rendered anyways, as they already are inside the viewport. So basically loading="lazy" is ignored in that case anyways.

I also see in this demo https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/img-loading-lazy that the pictures in the top of the dom are having the loading="lazy" attribute set.

I got the link above from: https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading/

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid setting `loading=lazy` for any images that are in the first visible viewport.

**Source:** https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/#avoid-lazy-loading-images-that-are-in-the-first-visible-viewport

In short, if the image is not loaded lazily, the browser can start fetching the resource immediately. Lazy images need to wait until the Layout phase of the browser rendering pipeline, to determine if an image is in the viewport or not.

Adding `loading=lazy` unnecessarily will likely add a small amount of delay until your webpage is fully rendered.

Answer (score -1):

One of the reasons I can think of to not always use lazy loading is when the network can be disrupted. In that case, you want to download as much as possible while the connection is active, so that the most of the page is usable when the connection is down.

Answer (score -1):

It’s a hint to the browser that the image might not be immediately useful/visible and that it should prioritize other resources. The third image in an image carousel or images appearing far down on the page are some good examples of when this attribute is useful.

[Overly lazy implementations](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/lazy-loading-viewports.html), such as Firefox, don’t images until they’re scrolled into view. This causes the browser to display a white area while the image is being loaded. This isn’t an ideal user-experience. Chrome, on the other hand, [loads images 3000–8000px](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/lazy-loading-viewports.html) before they appear on screen which is too eager again.

Chrome won’t load lazy-loaded images even when they’re within the viewport for background-opened tabs. This is caused by a limitation of Chromium’s `IntersectionObserver` and may be fixed in a future version.